# C# implementation of category and sub items

Tags: c#

In my application I maintain categories. Each category has some properties which influence the items which are part of the category. Such an item can only reside under one category. The category contains three properties now and determine which properties can be set of an item.

For example: Category A says that it is not possible to copy something. Items that resides under category A must then hide the copy property for the client. In the GUI the copy checkbox must also be invisible.

Items are always of the same type.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your question is a bit vague, but I'd do such a thing with interfaces. For example you can have an ICanCopy interface. If an object implements this interface you can display the copy checkbox on the UI.

In your example you can also create an ICannotCopy interface, and then hide the controls, but that seems counter-intuitive to me, I'd never model it that way.

EDIT: after some more clarification I'd advice you to look into the decorator pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

Comment: So, what you are saying is, everything that can be set in the category, create a new interface for that part? Which means, the item class has some properties where can 'inject' these interfaces. But how can I handle the GUI? How does the GUI whether or not to display the copy checkbox?

Comment: And, how would you model something like this?

Comment: what model are you talking about: domain model? database model?

Comment: Ok I think I understand your problem. I think the decorator pattern has a solution for you. I've put the link in my answer.

Comment: I've read into the decorator pattern. But I don't see how I can use this pattern. Maybe you can provide some (dummy) code?